# Обратное геокодирование нескольких меток на карте

Tags: геокодирование

Вывожу несколько меток на карте (в примере их 2, а так может быть больше 1000). У каждой метки имеются координаты. Пытаюсь вывести в подвал балуна адрес (полные адрес - страна, регион, город, улица и т.д.) метки, полученный по координатам. Адрес выводит, но только у последней метки (в примере Метка 2). Помогите вывести адрес по всем меткам, а не только по последней. Код писал по примерам. Сам в js не силен.

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

    var myPlacemark,

        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {

            center: [55.753994, 37.622093],

            zoom: 9

        }, {

            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'

        });

                myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(

                    [55.6285660,38.0576750],

                    {balloonContentHeader: "Метка 1",

                    balloonContentFooter: getAddress([55.6285660,38.0576750])

                });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

                myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(

                    [55.6314630,37.8488980],

                    {balloonContentHeader: "Метка 2",

                    balloonContentFooter: getAddress([55.6314630,37.8488980])

                });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

    // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).

            function getAddress(coords) {

                ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {

                    var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

                    myPlacemark.properties.set({

                            // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.

                            balloonContentFooter: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()

                        });

                });

            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [55.6285660,38.0576750],
    { balloonContentHeader: "Метка 1" }
  });
  getAddress([55.6314630,37.8488980], myPlacemark);
...

function getAddress(coords, placemark) {
  ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
    var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
    placemark.properties.set({
      balloonContentFooter: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!